# Number Guessing Game keeps repeating?

Tags: java, random, cycle

So I made this game where I pick a random number 1-100 and the computer guesses and I tell it too high, too low, or whatever. It works pretty good, except that it gets stuck in cycles when I try binary search and I can't seem to prevent it. I'll demonstrate:

Say the number is 79. Eventually, the program will ask if the number is 42. No, that's too low. Then it asks if it's 71. Guess higher! Then it asks 82. Nope, lower. Then it goes back to 42 and the cycle repeats over and over. Here's my code (note that it's an excerpt from the full code, so excuse the lack of the importation of JOptionPane and whatnot):

```
int x = 50;
int y = x;
int[] alreadyGuessed = {};
boolean secondGuess = false;
//The user has to select, too high, too low, correct!
while (secondGuess == false) {
    Object[] options = {"Too high", "Too Low", "Correct"};
    int pick = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Is your number " + x
            + "?", "Guess",
            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
            null, options, options[2]);
    for (int positionInList = 0; positionInList >= 100; positionInList++) {
       arrayDemo(x, positionInList);
    }

    if (pick == 0) {
       int max = x - 1;
       int min = 0;
       x = ((max + min) / 2);
    }

    if (pick == 1) {
       int max = 100;
       int min = x+1;
       x = ((max + min) / 2);
    }
    if (pick == 2) {
       System.out.println("Yay! I win!");
       secondGuess = true;

    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you set `min` to zero when the person selects "too high"? Why do you set `max` to 100 when the person select "too low"? And where do you track `min` and `max` across guesses?

Comment: Whoops, got that backwards

Comment: If the guess is too low, all you should do is raise the min to one more than the guess, right? And if the guess is too high, all you should do is lower the max to one less than the guess, right? Why do you change both min and max in each case?

Comment: Wait, no I didn't? If I have 79 as the answer and CPU guesses 90, that's too high, so 90-1 is the max and it can be as low as 0. What's wrong with that?

Comment: That's correct for the first guess. Now repeat that logic for the second guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of both min and max. So in your code, when you say `max = 100` or `min = 0`, the program is forgetting what the max & min are.

Delete those lines & you should be OK. In essence, you need to remember min & max all the way until you find the answer.

e.g. if the number is 42, min and max will be like:

```
0..100, guess 50 (too high)
0..49, guess 25 (too low)
26..49, guess 38 (too low)
39..49, guess 44 (too high)
39..43, guess 41 (too low)
42..43, guess 42 WIN!
```

Notice how both min and max zoom in on the answer. Carrying that information forward is what makes the strategy work.

Comment: But if I take out those lines, max and min aren't defined, and I can't do it outside the if statements because then each time the user presses a button, it will set max to 100 and min to 0 again.

Comment: Define min = 0 (or 1) and max = 100 at the start of the program, outside the main loop. `min = 0 max = 100 x = 50`

Comment: BTW if the program is losing state with each button click, then it's just not going to work. You'll need to find some way to carry min and max forward with each guess.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you so much. This has been bugging me for like a week and it's such a relief to complete it!

Comment: lol no worries; I had to stare at it for a while until I spotted the problem :)